# cannot add background color to Header/Footer in pdf

Tags: node.js, npm, puppeteer

I'm trying to customize the header and footer. But I cannot add the background color to the footer.
This is what I'm trying to do.

```
page.pdf({
    path: 'test.pdf',
    format: 'a4',
    landscape: '!data.isPortrait',
    footerTemplate: '<div class="footer" style="height:75px;position: absolute;top:auto;left:0px;right:0px;left:0px;background-color:red;">\ </div>',
    displayHeaderFooter: true,
    margin: {
        top: "75px",
        bottom: "75px"
    }
});
```

**environment**

```
Puppeteer version:1.1.0
Platform / OS version:ubuntu 16.04
Node.js version:8.9
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To add background-color to header/footer or to the page in Puppeteer, we need to add an additional css property, `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact`. Now it works fine.